# Android Flavors exclude duplicate class

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I have declared 2 flavors :

```
productFlavors
{
part1
  {
  }
 part2
  {
  }
}
```

I also have separete resources folders :

```
 sourceSets {
    part1 {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/part1/java']
        }
    }

    part2 {
        java
            {
            srcDirs = ['src/part2/java']
        }
    }
```

Part 1 contains : Main.java and Second.java

Part 2 contain only : Main.java

Everything is fine until i change the source jave for part 2 to :

```
srcDirs = ['src/part2/java','src/part1/java']
```

Because Main.java is in both parts i recive duplicate class error.

It's there a way to exlude for part2 the Main.java class from Part1 when i select part2 as build variant? And be able to compile part2 like this : Main.java ( from part2 source folder ) and Second.java (from part 1 source folder ) ?

Comment: Why are you giving `part1/java` as source dir for part2 flavor?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. All common sources which should be available in all flavors still have to be in src/main. All flavor specific sources belong in their respective folders. You **should not** specify your source sets. What are you doing that for?

Comment: If i put Main.java in the main folder it will also give me class duplicate on flavor which i wana overide Main.java.